# Some applications of Gronwall's inequality.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I've been trying to solve this problem:

**Problem:**

Lets consider the equation $\dot x = f(x) + g(x)$, lets suppose that $|f(x)|<1$ and that are some $\epsilon >0$ and $L>0$ such that $|g(x)|\leq \epsilon$. Lets suppose too, that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq L|x-y|$. If $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ are two solutions s.t $x_{1}(0) = x_{2}(0)$, **prove that $|x_{1}(t)-x_{2}(t)| \leq \frac{2\epsilon}{L}(e^{Lt}-1)$.**

**What I've done by now:**

Well, $$x_{1}(t) = x_{1}(0) + \int_{0}^{t} f(x_{1}(s))+g(x_{1}(s))ds$$
$$x_{2}(t) = x_{2}(0) + \int_{0}^{t} f(x_{2}(s))+g(x_{2}(s))ds$$

Then $x_{1}(t)-x_{2}(t)\leq x_{1}(0)-x_{2}(0) + \int_{0}^{t} f(x_{1}(s))-f(x_{2}(s))+g(x_{1}(s))-g(x_{2}(s))ds$, and finally,

$$|x_{1}(t)-x_{2}(t)|\leq \int_{0}^{t} |f(x_{1}(s))-f(x_{2}(s))|+ \int_{0}^{t} |g(x_{1}(s))-g(x_{2}(s))|ds$$

$$|x_{1}(t)-x_{2}(t)|\leq \int_{0}^{t} L|x_{1}(s)-x_{2}(s)|ds+ 2\epsilon tds$$

And since $2\epsilon t$ is non-decreasing we get to $$|x_{1}(t)-x_{2}(t)| \leq 2\epsilon t e^{Lt}$$

But I couldnt get a better bound :(

Any help is really appreciated, thanks so much :)

Comment: "and that are some $\epsilon >0$ and $L>0$ such that $|g(x)|\leq \epsilon$." is $L$ not used here, only later?

Comment: Thanls so much for your comment and nope, only in the bound for $|f(x)-f(y)|$

Comment: More specifically, $L$ is the *L*ipschitz constant of $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bounding function $u$ is a solution of the ODE
$$
\dot u=Lu+2ϵ,~~u(0)=0 \implies (e^{-Lt}u(t))'=2ϵe^{-Lt}\implies u(t)=\frac{2ϵ}{L}(e^{Lt}-1)
$$
as is claimed in the task.

To get there directly from the inequality, consider the differentiable function $\phi(t)=L\int_0^t|x_2(s)-x_1(s)|ds+2ϵ(t+a)$, $\phi(0)=2ϵa$, and its logarithmic derivative
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\log\phi(t)=\frac{L|x_2(t)-x_1(t)|+2ϵ}{\phi(t)}
\le\frac{L(\phi(t)-2ϵa)+2ϵ}{\phi(t)}=L
$$
The last equality is true if $a=1/L$. Then $\phi(t)\le \phi(0)e^{Lt}$ and this can be inserted into the original inequality
$$
|x_2(t)-x_1(t)|\le \phi(t)-2ϵa\le 2ϵa(e^{Lt}-1).
$$